# Pop-up upon first visit to select data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve a pop-up overlay window for a selector upon first page visit. A great example is the beer sites that ask if you are 21 and you click yes or no. A great example would be The Rare Barrel's site. I want the prompt to come up and they have two options and they forward to on of two sites based off of their selection.

I have been implementing https://github.com/chriscook/first-visit-popup but just get a gray overlay on the whole screen but no pop-up or selector.

Comment: any specific reason you are trying to use this plugin https://github.com/chriscook/first-visit-popup

Comment: No, It was just what I found and testing.

Comment: the reason you are getting the grey overlay because you changed it's selector name from `my-welcome-message`

Comment: if there is no specific reason, pass on this one, there is no API support, there is no callback function support, any modal can be triggered on page load, just have to make the modal DOM ready, example with bootstrap modal `$("#myModal").modal("show");` make this script DOM ready and it will show modal on page load.

Comment: example with bootstrap http://jsfiddle.net/4mge5c6w/

Comment: working example of firstvisit popup http://jsfiddle.net/memkhcbn/1/

Comment: a better example http://jsfiddle.net/memkhcbn/2/